# Callback from thread to calling class

Tags: java, multithreading

I currently have a class that extends `Thread`. In that class i get the contents of a web page (which is just JSON data) and i parse that. It depends what JSON object i get, because that determines what actions i take or what View i have to show.

But the way i'm currently doing it is i check in one class for all possible JSON request and perform actions based on that.

Example, my class kinda looks like this:

```
public class Communicator extends Thread
{
    Thread threadToInterrupt = null;
    String URL = null;

    public Houses ( String URL )
    {
        threadToInterrupt = Thread.currentThread();
        setDaemon(true);

        this.URL = URL;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // Code to get the JSON from a web page
        // Finally parse the result into a String
        String page = sb.toString();

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(page); 
        if ( !jObject.isNull("house") )
        {
            // do alot of stuff
        }
        else if ( !jObject.isNull("somethingelse") )
        {
            // do alot of other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, this class would soon be cluttered with alot of JSON checks and codes. This doesn't feel like it's the right way.

I thought, maybe it's better to pass in a callback method that gets invoked? So that i could change my class to something like this:

```
public class Communicator extends Thread
{
    Thread threadToInterrupt = null;
    String URL = null;

    public Houses ( String URL, String JsonString, object CallbackMethod )
    {
        // ... code
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // ....

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(page); 
        if ( !jObject.isNull(this.JsonString) )
        {
            // THen call the CallbackMethod...
            CallbackMethod ( jObject );
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyFunc()
    {
        (new Communicator("http://url.tld", "House", this.MyCallback)).start();
    }

    public void MyCallback(JSONObject jObject)
    {
        // Then i can perform actions here...
    }
}
```

---

Not sure if that is a good idea. But if so, how do i create a callback like in my example? Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You won't use a callback, but a handler object like MyJsonHandler:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyFunc()
    {
        (new Communicator("http://url.tld", "House", new MyJsonHandler())).start();
    }

}

public class MyJsonHandler() {

         public void handle(JsonObject jo) {
         // ...
          }

}
```

Or create a new MyJsonHandler just in place when you need:

```
public void run()
    {
        // ....

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(page); 
        if ( !jObject.isNull(this.JsonString) )
        {
            // THen call the CallbackMethod...
           new MyJsonHandler().handle(jObject);
        }
    }
```